# I have one shell script which I want to run via python script. I tried doing so using subprocess or os module , but nothing worked

Tags: python, shell, curl

```
       cd='np07lvg7omtn77s_APPID'
       cs='10f22edb0-ab0bc-4b82-b765-bb5927567118'
       b=`echo -n "$cd:$cs" | base64 -w 0`
       echo $b
```

Above is the shell script which I want to run via python script.I am getting the output as 250.  Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: Where is Python in this?

Comment: The commands you show work for me just fine.

Comment: Make sure you're running all the commands in the same subprocess. Variable assignments don't persist between processes.

Comment: What does `curl` have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['test.sh'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate() 

print(outs)
```

Replace test.sh with the path of your shell script